# Call a function every minute from a service worker for an offline PWA

Tags: javascript, push-notification, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, offlineapps

I'm working on a Progressive Web App (PWA) with offline support and I need to call a function in the app **every minute** from the service worker. (to send a web API based push notification if the user is offline)

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to call the function every minute use [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval):

```js
function myFunction(){
 console.log('called evry minute')
}

setInterval(myFunction, 1000);
```

But you can listen for `online` and `offline` events to send the notifications accordingly , see compatibility of [NavigatorOnLine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine) , as it won't work in `Opera`

```
window.addEventListener('online',  functionWhenOnline);
window.addEventListener('offline', functionWhenOffline);
```

Comment: will setinterval code work, even if user doesn't visit webpage?