# Is it possible to call a function in each minute in service worker

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I'm wondering, if it is possible to call a function in service worker in each minute. I didn't find any source for this. Is it possible? If yes, how? I'm new to service worker and had difficulties to understand its architecture and functionality.

So the function should run, even user doesn't visit webpage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call a function every minute from a service worker for an offline PWA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49825813/call-a-function-every-minute-from-a-service-worker-for-an-offline-pwa)

Comment: I don't think that this is a duplicate question. He asks something else. I need a code, which runs even if user doesn't visit webpage

Answer (score 0):

I have never used service worker before, but if its javascript, cant you just use setInterval(function() { // Your code here},1000)?